# Scrapy FormRequest.from_response error

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy, form-submit

I am tryping to scrape data from "https://pagesjaunes.fr". 
I on order to scrape the data from pagesjaunes: E-mail, adress etc I have first to submit the data in

When I search in the network chrome debuger to see the form data that is sent i can see a bunch of data that is probably generated on the fly by javascript.

[image]

and here is my python code for the spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
class PagesJaunes(scrapy.Spider):
    name="pagesjaunes"
    allowed_domains = [".fr", ".com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.pagesjaunes.fr"]

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,
        formdata = {
            "quoiqui": "macon",
            "ou":"bordeaux"
        },
        callback = self.parse_page2)

    def parse_page2(self, response):
        self.logger.info("%s page visited", response.url)
```

But it shows me this error:

```
2017-12-12 13:33:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2017-12-12 13:33:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'EDITOR': '/usr/bin/nano', 'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
2017-12-12 13:33:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2017-12-12 13:33:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-12-12 13:33:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-12-12 13:33:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-12-12 13:33:11 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-12-12 13:33:11 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-12-12 13:33:11 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-12-12 13:33:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.pagesjaunes.fr> (referer: None)
2017-12-12 13:33:13 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.pagesjaunes.fr': <POST https://www.pagesjaunes.fr/annuaire/chercherlespros?hp=1>
2017-12-12 13:33:13 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-12-12 13:33:13 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 216,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 19575,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 12, 11, 33, 13, 22520),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 52523008,
 'memusage/startup': 52523008,
 'offsite/domains': 1,
 'offsite/filtered': 1,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 12, 11, 33, 11, 466154)}
```

Am I setting the spider wrong or do I need a method to catch all the form data ?

Comment: check `Network -> XHR` in browser. It can use JavaScript (Ajax/XHR) to add data. And the In `XHR` you should find urls used to get data as json

Comment: I think there were question about this web page.

Comment: Indeed the page is live getting some part of data through ajax. After I checked there is no urls that i could use to get the data, and also the data that i am seeing is more related to platform variabeles: chromium ...os, etc. Nothing related to the search form. I think that the most part of the data neded for request form is generated thoughr js scrpits. I tried using scrapy-splash to pre-generate the data but somehow i can not find most of the variabels. It is really necessary to send the dictionary with all those post variabels. Could I use only 2 vars? It's somehow the code rong ?

Comment: See url in browser - it is `https://www.pagesjaunes.fr/annuaire/chercherlespros?quoiqui=macon&ou=Bordeaux`. You have `macon` and `Bordeaux` in url - so you don't need form to get it.

Comment: BTW: did you try code without `allowed_domains` ?

Comment: BTW: if you add `&page=2` then you get second page with data `https://www.pagesjaunes.fr/annuaire/chercherlespros?quoiqui=macon&ou=Bordeaux&page=2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses urls like

```
https://www.pagesjaunes.fr/annuaire/chercherlespros?quoiqui=‌​macon&ou=Bordeaux&pa‌​ge=2
```

so you can easily generate it using string formating with

```
?quoiqui={}&ou={}&page={}
```

I use `start_requests()` to add some urls to `start_urls` at start.

BTW: I use full domains to correctly work

```
allowed_domains = ["www.pagesjaunes.fr", "www.pagesjaunes.com"]
```

---

**EDIT:** I add new elements to code

Working example (without creating project)

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name="myspider"

    allowed_domains = ["www.pagesjaunes.fr", "www.pagesjaunes.com"]

    start_urls = []

    def start_requests(self):

        url = 'https://www.pagesjaunes.fr/annuaire/chercherlespros?quoiqui={}&ou={}&page={}'

        for page in range(5):
            yield scrapy.Request(url.format('macon', 'bordeaux', page)) #, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):

        self.logger.info("%s page visited", response.url)

        print('parse url >>>', response.url)

        for item in response.css('article'):
            title = item.css('.denomination-links ::text').extract_first().strip()
            tel = item.css('.bi-contact-tel strong ::text').extract_first().strip()

            email = item.css('.hidden-phone.SEL-email a ::attr(data-pjlb)').extract_first()
            if email:
                email = email[8:-17]
                email = base64.b64decode(email)
                url = response.joinurl(email)
                yield scrapy.Response(url, callback=parse_email, meta={'title': title, 'tel': tel})

            print('title', title, ', tel', tel, 'email:', email)

            yield {'title': title, 'tel': tel, 'email:': email}

    def parse_email(self, response):

        print('parse_email url  >>>', response.url)
        print('parse_email meta >>>', response.meta)

# --- it runs without project and saves in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv',
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

---

**EDIT:** after many requests (more then 1000 pages) it was blocked by server with

```
(403) <GET https://www.pagesjaunes.fr/annuaire/chercherlespros?quoiqui=macon&ou=bordeaux&page=3>
```

which shows

[image]

Comment: Yep that's a bit of problem. I found something that could bypass this http://sangaline.com/post/advanced-web-scraping-tutorial/

Comment: as I know scrapy can use proxy servers to connect to web page - and this could helps but sometimes it is hard to find good and free proxy servers.